# How to protect a stopwatch during a test assessment?

Tags: php, oop, pdo, stopwatch

I want to know how i can set up a stopwatch and prevent him agaist cheat.
I was going to use

- `date()`
- `$_SERVER['DATE_GMT']`
- `$_SERVER['DATE_LOCAL']`

But I don't know if it is a good method and if I am on good way.

The test assessment must be portected against modification (endof test) when the time is over, and I want to check if `$end_test = $end_planned` which is `$start_test + 60min`.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the time they start at in a database or external file. Then when they reload the test you would need get the time they started the test, the current time, and calculate if they still have time.

When they submit the test you would check the same thing.

You would have to give students a unique PIN to use so when you store it, it can be looked up again.

Something like this might work.

When they load the page ask them for their unique PIN:

```
$test_duration = 30; // minutes
$test_duration *= 60; // turning into sections for later use

// check if results from a PIN lookup are empty
if($pin_from_db == "") { // there no pin in the database. Student didn't start yet
   $sql = "INSERT INTO example_student_table(student_id, start_time) VALUES ($student_id, " . date('U') . ")";
   $start = date('U');
} else { // there was a PIN in the Database
   $start = (int)$time_from_db;
}

// check if they still have time left
if($start < (date('U') + $start)) {
   // let them do the test
} else {
   // dont let them continue the test
}
```

Your form would look something like this

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post">
   // what ever other questions you need answered put here
   <input type="hidden" name="end_time" value="<?php echo $start + $test_duration" />
</form>
```

Then when they submit the page your 'processor.php' could check to see if they did it in the allotted time

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
   $allotment = $_POST['end_time'];
   $now       = date('U');
   if($now <= $allotment) {
      // they finished in time
   } else {
      // they didn't finish in time
   }
}
```